# Can I be banned/barred from the mall for a year without being served papers?

Tags: united-states, is-x-legal

Can I be banned from the mall which is private property without being served papers? I do work there. I was caught sleeping in a hallway. So they banned me for a year I now lost my job because of it. They told my job I had to be fired? Is this legal without papers? Police and security escort me out though and was verbally told so does that count? Also what is my best corse of action to get the ban lifted. I love this job I don’t want to lose it. Help!

Comment: Did your boss actually tell you that you're fired? Which state is this in?

Comment: Their mall, their rules ?

Comment: No he didn’t but my wife works there n told me security said I have to be